# Accessing RabbitMQ using svc.cluster.local URL

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

I have RabbitMQ service running in an AKS (Azure Kubernetes Service) cluster as type LoadBalancer. While I am able to use the pod and service IP by providing `http://<IP address>:<port number>/` to access RabbitMQ management page on VMs peered to the cluster's VNET, I am not able to access the page using `http://<servicename>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local` URL with or without the ports appended. What could be done for this to work?

Comment: Can you access other services by DNS ?

Comment: Other services are routed through application gateway and are publicly accessible. RabbitMQ is used as a message queue service and while pods are happily communicating with each other, there are developer VMs which need to connect to it. That's where the problem is now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered that the svc.cluster.local URLs resolve to the cluster IP and not external IP of the Load Balancer service. I figured this out after running a `nslookup <URL>` from one of the pods in the namespace. I am now evaluating the possibility of setting a static IP for the external IP or use the Azure application gateway.